# Java Spring WebFlux Multipart File Upload

Tags: java, spring, file-upload

I am trying to make simple post-request with a image. But it is not working.

My html post form data (multipart/form-data) :

```
book[0].cover = 123.jpg;  <--- upload file image
book[0].title = "title 123";
book[0].author = "123"

book[1].cover = abc.jpg;
book[1].title = "title abc";
book[1].author = "abc"
```

[restapi image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLU6g.png)

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1/book/postCreate \
    -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
    -d 'book%5B0%5D.file=[$file.30378169-jpg]&book%5B0%5D.title=title%20123&book%5B0%5D.author=author%20123&book%5B1%5D.file=[$file.30378190-jpg]&book%5B1%5D.title=title%20abc&book%5B0%5D.author=author%20abc'
```

My controller method is setup as follows:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> postCreate(ServerRequest request) {
    Flux<Book> book = request.bodyToFlux(Book.class);  // error
    // How can I get the data of the form ?
}

class Book {
    FilePart cover;
    String title;
    String author;
}
```

**How can I get the data of the form ?**

Answer (score 0):

Im not the best at java, but when I go into visual studio code and enter this in, it gives me a couple of errors.

```
book[0].cover = 123.jpg;  <--- uplaod file image
book[0].title = "title 123";
book[0].author = "123"

book[1].cover = abc.jpg;
book[1].title = "title abc";
book[1].author = "abc"
```

first of all, upload is spelt wrong, that's probably why. When I click on the word "file" in visual studio code it will just change to "File" not "file". I think capitalization is the problem here but I'm not fluent in java.

Like I said, I'm not fluent in java because I code python and sometimes JavaScript but I have never seen a error like this.

Comment: Hi! this is html form data examples